# Javascript putting object inside arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I'm having some troubles using Javascript. I have a list of bottles (more than a 100) and each of those have different specifities (price, name,alchool, etc). I wish to make a simple and organized "database " per say.

Maybe if I show this you would understand the gist of what I'm trying to do.

```js
var tequila = [{name:"José",price:16.35,concen:"38",alctype:"blanco", quant:0},
{name:"El Jimador",price:22.45,concen:38,alctype:"blanco", quant:0},
{name:"Gran Centenario Plata Tequila",price:29.75,concen:38,alctype:"blanco", quant:0},
{name:"1800 Silver",price:31.25,concen:38,alctype:"blanco", quant:0},
{name:"Herradura",price:37.45,concen:38,alctype:"blanco", quant:0}
]
document.getElementById("fafa").innerHTML = tequila[3].price;
```

```html
<p id="fafa"></p>
```

By doing this doc-get-element `tequila[3].price` I wish to access the price of the the third bottle in the list.

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I have been searching around and I couldn't find a person who's had this similar issue. Is the syntax wrong? 
Or does this feature not exist in Javascript?

Thank you for your time, I appreciate any tips and pointers you could give me.

Comment: `price` !== `prix`!

Comment: Thank you for showing me the typo mistake. When writing this on the website, I made the translations but forgot that last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works well. Just make sure that the `tequila` has array type instead of string otherwise you need to do `JSON.parse(tequila)` before accessing the value.

```js
var tequila = [{name:"José",price:16.35,concen:"38",alctype:"blanco", quant:0},
{name:"El Jimador",price:22.45,concen:38,alctype:"blanco", quant:0},
{name:"Gran Centenario Plata Tequila",price:29.75,concen:38,alctype:"blanco", quant:0},
{name:"1800 Silver",price:31.25,concen:38,alctype:"blanco", quant:0},
{name:"Herradura",price:37.45,concen:38,alctype:"blanco", quant:0}
]
document.getElementById("fafa").innerHTML = tequila[3].price;
```

```html
<p id="fafa"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

As array index start from 0.
then you should do `tequila[2].price` for getting 3rd bottle price.

Answer (score -1):

It's a typo, you misspelled price to prix

Answer (score -1):

Trying using like this

```
Object(tequila[3].price)
```

Comment: This makes no sense at all.